# Connecting an external speakerphone with Android phone using USB

Tags: android, usb, webrtc, usb-otg, speakerphone

Problem: If I make a Google Hangout call from my Android phone and want to use an external speakerphone [Jabra speak 410](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004ELA7TA). The only way I could make Hangouts use this device was to connect it with Bluetooth.

I want to use a USB cable connection and have WebRTC based conference app e.g. Google Hangouts detect and use the mic and speaker of that Jabra device and not the Android phone.

Comment: Audio routing is not transparent on Android. These apps have dedicated code to detect TRS or BT earpiece and let the end-user choose it.

Comment: @AlexCohn thank you for your insight. I am currently trying to build a webRTC demo app for Android and want to implement choosing the right device when something is connected via USB/cable (and NOT bluetooth).